# A variation on $6=2 \cdot 3=(1+\sqrt {-5})(1-\sqrt {-5})$

Tags: commutative-algebra, integral-domain, unique-factorization-domains

In the integral domain $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt {-5}]$, we have $6=2 \cdot 3=(1+\sqrt {-5})(1-\sqrt {-5})$, so it is not a UFD (two different decompositions of $6$).

$2$ divides $6$, but $2$ does not divide $1+\sqrt {-5}$ nor $1-\sqrt {-5}$.

> **(1)** Could one present an example of an integral domain $D$ in which an element $d \in D$ divides $a^n$ but $d$ does not divide $a$? where $a \in D$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Define property $P$ in an integral domain the following property: 
If an element $d \in D$ divides $a^n$, then $d$ divides $a$, where $a \in D$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

(Is it true that Property $P$ characterizes [GCD domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain)?).

> **(2)** What is known about integral domains satisfying property $P$?
>   Is it true that $\mathbb{Z} [\sqrt {-5}]$ satisfies property $P$?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The integers are an example of (1):  $12 \mid 6^2$ but $12$ does not divide $6$. Maybe you were sloppy with your use of quantifiers. (Stylistically, it'd be better to write $\sqrt{-5}$ instead of $\sqrt{5}i$. Neither $\sqrt{5}$ nor $i$ is in $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-5}]$.)

Comment: @KCd, thank you for your comment! Actually, I had in mind an irreducible $d$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[ \sqrt {-5}]$ does not satisfy property $P$..

Comment: The question may benefit from refinements, but I proffer the following examples related to (1), adding the assumption that $d$ should be irreducible.

$$A)\ D=\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}], d=2, a=1+\sqrt{-5}, n=2$$
as $a^2=-4+2\sqrt{-5}$ is divisible by two.

$$B)\ D=\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}], d=1+\sqrt{-7}, a=2, n=3.$$
Here $a^n=8=(1+\sqrt{-7})(1-\sqrt{-7})$, but $d$ is irreducible. Observe that in the integral closure of $D$ we have $$2=\frac{1+\sqrt{-7}}2\cdot\frac{1-\sqrt{-7}}2.$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, thank you for your two examples. I wonder if in such integral domains it is possible to distinguish between irreducible elements behaving like prime elements or not.

Comment: Perhaps the easiest example is: $D=k[x^2,x^3]$, $d=x^2$, $a=x^3$, $n=2$. Clearly, $x^2 | x^6=x^2x^2x^2$, but $x^2$ does not divide $x^3$.

Comment: The ideal $Dx^2$ is not a radical ideal in $D$, since $(x^3)^2=x^2x^2x^2 \in Dx^2$, but $x^3 \notin Dx^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'll think of an example for $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ after I log off. But I thought of one in $D = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-15})}$ before I even finished reading your question.

> **(1)** Could one present an example of an integral domain $D$ in which an element $d \in D$ divides $a^n$ but $d$ does not divide $a$? where $a \in D$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Consider $$d = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{-15}}{2}$$ (which is an algebraic integer with minimal polynomial $x^2 - x + 4$), $a = 2$, $n = 4$. Then $d \mid a^n$, but $d \nmid a$, since $$\frac{2}{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{-15}}{2}} = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{\sqrt{-15}}{4}$$ is an algebraic number but not an algebraic integer (minimal polynomial $2x^2 - x + 2$). You'll see much the same thing with the conjugate of $d$.

Actually, not sure I'll be able to squeak it in before I have to go, but I just remembered about $(2 - \sqrt{-5})(2 + \sqrt{-5}) = 3^2$, which the

As for property $P$, I'm inclined to say that it is true of GCD domains but not others, though I could be overlooking something commutative that I ought to know about but can't remember at the moment.

In either case, I can tell you that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ doesn't have property $P$, since then of